# Error on activate account alphanet on docker

Tags: node, docker, alphanet

I got a problem while running "activate account" with alphanet on docker (see image below). How do I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

General remarks: raw text snapshots are more convenient for developers than pictures because you can quote them :-)

It looks like `tezos-client` does not understand the "uri" format `file:/[...]`. It's an annoying bug which is worth reporting at https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues .

I don't know if docker keeps the files it puts in `/tmp/` or if it erases them immediately. If files stay for a bit, now that the son file is in the container, `alphabet.sh client activate account peach with /tmp/tz1....json` should work...

Comment: and Now I can run tezos-client finish but I can't activate account success , How do I fixed it ? ...                                                                                                                              
`Fatal error: The operation opAguJg1GCLJUQ1qShiQDAcC56Zv41nZJcaePz8mGj21CSnfEKe is outdated and may never be included in the chain.
  We recommand to use an external block explorer.`

Comment: I am also getting the same error when I run "./alphanet.sh client activate account user_1 with tz1xxx...xxxxxubq.json" When json file is in the same folder of alphanet.sh script. 
Error thrown was:
Erroneous command line argument 5 (tz1xxx...xxxxxubq.json).
  File doesn't exist: 'tz1xxx...xxxxxubq.json' 

How did you solve it?

Comment: Also, I made the local set up via "Build from Sources" option and was getting the outdated error you mentioned in the comment. HOw did you resolved that?

Answer (score 2):

Okay so this is my first stackexchange answer ever and I'm surprised I was the one to figure this out but here's what I did after several hours.

The problem is that docker cannot access the place in your filesystem that has your temp wallet in it. So I found this article detailing how to mount a volume to a docker container while it is running: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/01/13/docker-mount-dynamic-volumes/

You need to find the name of your tezos node with

> docker ps

(1) Mine is called

> alphanet_node_1

(2) Next you need to find the location of your .json file. Mine is in

> ~/Downloads/tezos_docker/tz1....json

(3) Next enter your container with >./alphanet.sh shell
then create the directory in the container you want to contain the .json file. Mine is

> /home/tezos/tezos_docker

Use those three values for the variables at the top of the script in the linked article at the top:

> CONTAINER=(1)
>   HOSTPATH= (2)
>   CONTPATH= (3)

Also make sure you download the nsenter script from the linked article using

> docker run --rm -v /usr/local/bin:/target jpetazzo/nsenter

Finally I had to change some of the syntax at the bottom of the script in the article, deleting the 
-- in the bottom rows and changing --mode to -m for mknod. Hope this helps!

Comment: heroic! answering a question back from march, welcome to TSE!